# Create SQL Server database and tables from vb.net programmatically without using SQL Server Management Studio in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Can you help how to create a SQL Server database and a table inside it just programmatically without going to open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

One day I tried to create a table to an existing database and I succeeded creating it BUT one problem I'm having every time it began throwing an error

> There is already an object named ('xxxx')  in this database.

The error every time I try insert a data to it the data are saved but I want to get rid of this error message. How to prevent this SQL Server error using try catch statement in Vb language code?

Another question I know sometimes there are errors which are thrown from SQL Server itself; so how to catch errors that are sometimes thrown from SQL Server itself and capture and store those error to some thing like a window form control such as messagebox or label or else so that user can be aware of those errors?

I hope someone knows in here please help I'm here to learn and I appreciate your contribution

Code I tried:

```
Private Sub btnsaveextension_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsaveextension.Click
    Try
        stringQuery=  "if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='Contract_TimeExtension' and xtype='U') USE MyFirstDB " & _
                      "CREATE TABLE [Contract_TimeExtension] ([Extension No] Integer  NOT NULL,[Extension Approaved Date] Date NOT NULL," & _
                      "[Contractor Received Date] Date NOT NULL,[Extension Notes] Nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,[New Extended Date] Date NOT NULL, " & _
                      "[Contract ID]nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,[Contract Name] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL);")
    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code and get our help specifically.

Comment: The code I tried is this below

Comment: The code is shown at the end of the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of the commands in your query are wrong.

`USE MyFirstDB` is called directly after the `IF EXISTS(...)`-part.

Now if the table already exists, only the `USE MyFirstDB`-part is skipped, but not `CREATE TABLE...`.

You can either move `USE MyFirstDB` to the beginnig of the query or remove it completely as the database is usually already defined in the connection string.

---

To separately catch [SQL exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can add an additional `Catch` tho the `Try`-block as follows:

```vb
Try
    ' your code here
Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    MsgBox("SqlException thrown: " & ex.Message)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```